# Detect System Service Tag using JS

Tags: javascript, browser

Here i am trying to get system service tag/BIOS id using JS just Like Dell do.

Is there any way to call installed application from js.?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That would not be possible via javascript, within browser context. So, no,.there is not a way. Back at the drawing board, as they say - LOL

Comment: Then how the dell driver website can automatically detect my system Info.

Comment: They likely use software external to the browser, which the browser communicates with via a median remote website, or via a browser extension (if those even have elevated permissions). Inspect your machine, and you will likely find some dell software installed. Such software has elevated permissions, while browser doesn't. That's how.

Comment: Yes dell-support application is there , i am trying to know how they access that application from js via browser.

Comment: they dont. that installed app reads that value from the operating system, then thwy have some mechanism of passing that value to the webpage running within the browser. That mechanism is likely a remote webservice, which receives the value sent by the app, and then makes it available.to the browser script when it asks. You can see which network calls the browser is making via dev tools

Comment: or maybe their installed app launched an http listener at some port, and so you might finf http:// localhost:someport in that trace (F12 > network.tab). Inspect what the browser is doing, maybe you can mimick. But even if you're successful, it will only work on machines with that software installed and running. What do you need that value for anyway?